# Core overlay on path defined in views

Tags: views, modal-dialogs

Anyone know how to render a path defined in a view in the core overlay.

hook_admin_paths_alter() does not work in that instance. I can only think that it has to do with the execution pipeline.

overlay_paths module also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to Change the overlay permissions and make the overlay view accessed by Visitors and users

[image]

lets Implement Hook_admin_path_alter in your custom module...

```
function YOURMODULENAME_admin_paths_alter(&$path) {
  $path['VIEWPATH'] = TRUE;
}
```

Clear Drupal Cache..

Comment: Thank you Anil. I tried that on another view and it worked fine. However, my specific use case has a view with this path:
node/%/product-variations

and neither 
function price_tables_admin_paths_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%/product-variations'] = TRUE;
}

nor

function price_tables_admin_paths_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/product-variations'] = TRUE;
}

works.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem using  $items['node/*/product-variations'] = TRUE;